# Lock cursor position to mouse

Tags: front-end, java, interactive

I would like to lock the cursor position, i.e. the insertion point, to the current position of the mouse at all times in a given notebook.

An experiment with J/Link approximates this, by repeatedly simulating left mouse button clicks:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
ReinstallJava[];
robotclass = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"];
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.event.InputEvent"];

click[] := Block[{},
   robotclass@mousePress[InputEvent`BUTTON1UMASK];
   robotclass@mouseRelease[InputEvent`BUTTON1UMASK];
   ];

Do[click[], 1000]
```

but this results in repeatedly expanding the current selection. (Ideally I would like to still use the physical left mouse button to expand the current selection.)

A second experiment recursively clicks, but allows a proper system click to pass through only after some time and cursor distance has passed:

```
LastTime = AbsoluteTime[];
LastMousePosition = MousePosition[];
SetClickOptions[pass_] := SetOptions[InputNotebook[],
  NotebookEventActions -> {"MouseClicked" :> Block[{},
      If[
        EuclideanDistance[LastMousePosition, MousePosition[]] > 4
         &&
         AbsoluteTime[] - LastTime > 0.01
        ,
        LastMousePosition = MousePosition[];
        LastTime = AbsoluteTime[];
        SetClickOptions[True];
        ,
        SetClickOptions[False];
        ];

        click[];
      ],

      PassEventsDown -> pass}]
```

Run this with

```
SetClickOptions[False]
```

and a single click, and keep this lifebuoy nearby:

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
 NotebookEventActions -> {"MouseClicked" :> "", 
   PassEventsDown -> True}]
```

This second piece of code still has the problem of selecting entire pieces of expressions, especially when mousing over a new line.

Comment: Is there a good reason behind this wish? :)